# Crash on iOS 16+ _nw_path_evaluator_call_update_handler_block_invoke NWPathMonitor.pathUpdateHandler callback in Network framework of apple

Tags: ios, swift, crash, ios16

Trying to monitor network changes in iOS app with Network framework from apple.

```
import Foundation
import Network

protocol NWPathMonitorInterface {
    var pathUpdateHandler: ((_ newPath: NWPath) -> Void)? {get set}
    func start(queue: DispatchQueue)
    func cancel()
}

extension NWPathMonitor: NWPathMonitorInterface {}

final class ReachabilityManager {
   
   private(set) var isNetworkAvailable: Bool = false
   private(set) var connectionType: NWInterface.InterfaceType?
   
   private let queue: DispatchQueue
   private var monitor: NWPathMonitorInterface?
   
   public var onUpdateNetworkStatus: ((Bool) -> Void)?
   static let shared = ReachabilityManager(monitor: NWPathMonitor(),
                                           queue: DispatchQueue(label: "com.rapido.networkMonitoring"))

   deinit {
       stopMonitoring()
   }
   
   init(monitor: NWPathMonitorInterface,
        queue: DispatchQueue) {
       self.monitor = monitor
       self.queue = queue
   }
   
   enum ConnectionType {
       case wifi
       case cellular
       case ethernet
   }
   
   public func startMonitoring() {
       if monitor == nil {
           monitor = NWPathMonitor()
       }
       self.monitor?.start(queue: queue)
       self.monitor?
           .pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
               guard let self = self else { return }
               self.updateStatus(status: path.status)
               self.updateConnectionType(interface: path
                   .availableInterfaces
                   .map(\.type))
       }
   }
   
   
   func updateStatus(status: NWPath.Status) {
       isNetworkAvailable = status == .satisfied ? true : false
       onUpdateNetworkStatus?(isNetworkAvailable)
   }
   
   func updateConnectionType(interface: [NWInterface.InterfaceType]) {
       connectionType = interface.first
   }
   
   func stopMonitoring() {
       monitor?.cancel()
       monitor = nil
   }
}
```

Start Monitoring when application state change to foreground and stop monitoring when application enter background

```
 func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
          ReachabilityManager.shared.startMonitoring()
 }

 func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        ReachabilityManager.shared.stopMonitoring()
 }
```

[image: crash]

Adding crash log

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x3da1bc _swift_release_dealloc + 32
1  libswiftNetwork.dylib          0x372a4 closure #1 in NWPathMonitor.init(requiredInterfaceType:) + 296
2  libswiftNetwork.dylib          0x2470 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed OS_nw_path) -> () + 52
3  Network                        0x91dad8 __nw_path_evaluator_call_update_handler_block_invoke + 336
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x24b4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x70c8 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 788
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x15a6c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x16284 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xdbc _pthread_wqthread + 228
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb98 start_wqthread + 8
```

One strange thing about crash happen only in iOS 16+ devices and 23% background state. I am not able to reproduce this still locally as frequency is very low. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems somehow instance of `NWMonitor` get dealloc in some edge although not replicated to me. Adding more sanity with `isMonitoring` flag. Now it is 100% crash free.

Updated code

```
import Network

protocol NWPathMonitorInterface {
     var pathUpdateHandler: ((_ newPath: NWPath) -> Void)? {get set}
     func start(queue: DispatchQueue)
     func cancel()
     var currentPath: NWPath { get }
}

extension NWPathMonitor: NWPathMonitorInterface {}

final class ReachabilityManager {
    
    private(set) var isNetworkAvailable: Bool = false
    private(set) var connectionType: NWInterface.InterfaceType?
    private(set) var isMonitoring: Bool = false
    
    private let queue: DispatchQueue
    private var monitor: NWPathMonitorInterface?
    
    public var onUpdateNetworkStatus: ((Bool) -> Void)?
    static let shared = ReachabilityManager(monitor: NWPathMonitor(),
                                            queue: DispatchQueue(label: "com.rapido.networkMonitoring"))

    deinit {
        stopMonitoring()
    }
    
    init(monitor: NWPathMonitorInterface,
         queue: DispatchQueue) {
        self.monitor = monitor
        self.queue = queue
    }
    
    enum ConnectionType {
        case wifi
        case cellular
        case ethernet
    }
    
    public func startMonitoring() {
        guard !isMonitoring else {
            return
        }
        if monitor == nil {
            monitor = NWPathMonitor()
        }
        self.monitor?.start(queue: queue)
        self.monitor?
            .pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] status in
                guard let self = self,
                      let monitor = self.monitor else { return }
            
                self.updateStatus(status: monitor.currentPath.status)
                self.updateConnectionType(interface: monitor.currentPath
                    .availableInterfaces
                    .map(\.type))
        }
        isMonitoring = true
    }
    
    
    func updateStatus(status: NWPath.Status) {
        isNetworkAvailable = status == .satisfied ? true : false
        onUpdateNetworkStatus?(isNetworkAvailable)
    }
    
    func updateConnectionType(interface: [NWInterface.InterfaceType]) {
        connectionType = interface.first
    }
    
    func stopMonitoring() {
        monitor?.cancel()
        monitor = nil
        isMonitoring = false 
    }
}
```